# Can I have My Photo Stream upload only?

Tags: ios, photo-stream

I have a iPad and a iPhone. My iPhone don't have enough storage so I want to disable downloading photo from Photo Stream. However, I do want iPhone to upload the photos to Photo stream and access & download it on my iPad. Is their anyway I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is enable iCloud Photo Library on all devices, and then disable photo stream (or at least optimise storage) on your mobile devices. iCloud Photo Library is the actual cloud storage, while Photo Stream is just syncing between your devices (and not the cloud).

Note that Photo Stream only keeps your last 1000 items downloaded on a device. Photo Stream provides no backup if you lose all devices at the same time (if you carry them all with you and something happens).

Comment: I don't want to use iCloud Photo Library as I have too many photos. :)

Comment: I strongly suggest using a cloud service, at least on some level, to keep your memories safe. Think about what happens if you lose all devices simulatenously. The cheapest cloud packages are hopefully reasonably priced in most countries. If you stay on Photo Stream, you could keep full size originals at the iPad and then optimise storage on your iPhone (I'm guessing the pad has more storage).